# My iPhone cannot "see" all the books on my Mac via Mojave iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, books

I have 18 books in Books.app on my MacBook Pro running Mojave. When I open iTunes and look at the Books on my phone, it shows 5 books.

Changing the iTunes radiobutton from "All books" to "Selected books" lets me select among those 5. As far as I can tell, the other 13 are invisible to it.

Any clues where to look, what settings to change, what to reboot (again), or whatever?

Please don't tell me to upgrade my OS X version, since I have too much expensive 32-bit software to make that attractive.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had found a fix for my situation in this post:

> "iBooks does not seem to be recognizing that books have been previously purchased when the purchase price has changed."

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8613752 (Not the most meaningful questions because it presupposes the problem, which turns out no to be the case.)

After doing as suggested, "Books -> File -> Move Books From iTunes", then resyncing my Books, everything was in my Library, as expected.  I had previously not been able to find *any* explanation of what "Move Books From iTunes" was about or what it did.

So I reported that here as an "Answer". Except that it didn't last.

Now, of 18 books in Books on my Mac, iTunes Devices > My iPhone > Books shows 8 of them. A few minutes ago it showed 5 and then I did the "Move Books From iTunes" routine again. It reported that it was moving 15 books. I don't know which ones are missing from the 15 because I now only show 6 of them after updating. 5 books, a different 5, then 8, now 6. And the current 6 does not include *any* of the ones I'm actually reading. I would quit trying if and when I finally got all 3 of those on the iPhone at the same time.

I keep restarting iTunes, rebooting my iPhone, restarting Books on the Mac, running the "Move Books From iTunes" routine, in hopes that some combination will be the magic sequence of what is being updated in what order so that I can read those three books on my iPhone. Right now, it can't even "see" them to allow me to select them.

---

**Update**: It appears that every time I run the Books "utility" File > Move books from iTunes, I toggle between two sets of books. One set has 6 books and the other 16, with a total of 18 different books. I have no clue what put which books in which list.

Unfortunately, there are two books that I am in the middle of, one happens to be in each list, so I cannot switch between those books without connecting my iPhone to my Mac, using "Move books from iTunes" to get the other list active, and then syncing that list. My previous set of books disappears off my phone, replaced by the new set. Then I can read in the other book. I repeat that when I want to go back to the first book. This will probably force me to just finish one or the other book by brute force, rather than following my whims. Oh well.